# How to enforce that WPF (popup) window resizes before it's visible?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, resize, window, sizetocontent

I'm using a pop-up window in my WPF application. It's a borderless window with `SizeToContent` set to `WidthAndHeight`.

It resizes itself every time I show it to the user in order to accomodate for various lengths of caption on the button and the number of buttons which can vary etc.

Unfortunately, this auto-resizing is noticeable - especially when the window shrinks; it looks "jumpy" and thus sort of amateurish.

I'm never disposing of this window - just hiding and showing again - because I'd have to reattach some event handlers every time, and also repopulate a listbox (with language codes), which I'm not sure I should do.

Is there any way I could tell it to calculate the right size *before* it is displayed?

Comment: It must be WPF perf optimization, did you try calling InvalidateMeasure()?

Comment: Yeah it seems to look better. I'm new to WPF. Cheers!

Comment: @Dmitry: Please post that as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be WPF perf optimization. Calling InvalidateMeasure() beforehands might help.